# Is it possible to view unconfirmed transactions with the bitcoin client?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

This site shows you unconfirmed bitcoin transactions:
https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions

As I understand it, these unconfirmed transactions are received and rebroadcast by every bitcoin client. Given that they are on my computer, how would I go about extracting this information (i.e. a list of all unconfirmed bitcoin transactions) from the bitcoin client?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The RPC interface includes the `getrawmempool` command which returns transactions in your memory pool. Transactions stay in your memory pool until they're confirmed, so this is effetively a list your known unconfirmed transacions.

Since `getrawmempool` returns only a list of transaction ids, you'll have to `getrawtransaction <txid>` for each transaction id in your memory pool. Remember you can get JSON-formmated output via `getrawtransaction <txid> 1`.

Comment: It may be out of date, see https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getrawmempool it appears `getrawmempool` already has extra argument for tx details